# How to count the most recent value based on multiple criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I keep a log of phone calls like the following where the F column is LVM = Left Voice Mail, U = Unsuccessful, S = Successful.

```
A1 1  B1 Smith   C1 John  D1 11/21/2012  E1 8:00 AM  F1 LVM  

A2 2  B2 Smith   C2 John  D2 11/22/2012  E1 8:15 AM  F2 U

A3 3  B3 Harvey  C3 Luke  D3 11/22/2012  E1 8:30 AM  F3 S

A4 4  B4 Smith   C4 John  D4 11/22/2012  E1 9:00 AM  F4 S

A5 5  B5 Smith   C5 John  D5 11/23/2012  E5 8:00 AM  F5 LVM
```

This is a small sample.  I actually have over 700 entries.  In my line of work, it is important to know how many unsuccessful (LVM or U) calls I have made since the last Successful one (S).  Since values in the F column can repeat, I need to take into consideration both the B and C column.

Also, since I can make a successful call with a client and then be trying to contact them again, I need to be able to count from the last successful call.  My G column is completely open which is where I would like to put a running total for each client (G5 would = 1 ideally while G4 = 0, G3 = 0, G2 = 2, G1 = 1 but I want these values calculated automatically so that I do not have scroll through 700 names).

Comment: Do you know much about VBa?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the liberty of adding a header row and have replaced your numbers in ColumnA (these effectively match the row numbers, so hopefully not required) with `=B2&“ ”&A2` etc (to distinguish individuals who might share Surname or FirstName with others). Then the formula:

```
=SUM(IF(F2<>"S",G1+IF(F2="S",0,MATCH(A2,A2:A$700,0)),0))
```

will hopefully suit – though I have not tested it much beyond the data you have provided.

[image]

If this works I may come back later and explain how - but no point if it does not!

Comment: I like it and it seems simple enough.  I will work on it and double check!  Thank you!

Comment: *Update*  I notice a slight problem.  As you have this currently set, all of column G will add the previous value (as long as the current F is S) even if the Name is different.  I believe that your placement of G1 must move.  I will work on it and update when I know more.

Comment: Number  Last    First   Date            Time    Result  Calls since 694. As Ha 11/21/2012 7:35 AM S 0
695. Gi Ni 11/21/2012 8:32 AM LVM 7
696. Ki Dy 11/21/2012 8:40 AM LVM 6
697. Le Ke 11/21/2012 8:47 AM S 0
698. Li Sp 11/21/2012 9:08 AM LVM 1
699. Or Ha 11/21/2012 9:48 AM LVM 4
700. Li Sp 11/21/2012     10:04 AM S 0
701. He Am 11/21/2012     10:26 AM S 0
702. Th Ca 11/21/2012     10:42 AM S ~ 1
703. Va Ju 11/21/2012     10:52 AM LVM 2
704. Fr No 11/21/2012     12:35 PM S 0
705. Ki Dy 11/21/2012     12:49 PM S 0
706. Ha Jo 11/21/2012 1:16 PM S ~ 2

Comment: A       B       C       D               E       F       G    Number  Last    First   Date            Time    Result  Calls since 694. As Ha 11/21/2012 7:35 AM S 0
695. Gi Ni 11/21/2012 8:32 AM LVM 7
696. Ki Dy 11/21/2012 8:40 AM LVM 6
697. Le Ke 11/21/2012 8:47 AM S 0
698. Li Sp 11/21/2012 9:08 AM LVM 1
699. Or Ha 11/21/2012 9:48 AM LVM 4
700. Li Sp 11/21/2012     10:04 AM S 0
701. He Am 11/21/2012     10:26 AM S 0
702. Th Ca 11/21/2012     10:42 AM S ~ 1
703. Va Ju 11/21/2012     10:52 AM LVM 2
704. Fr No 11/21/2012     12:35 PM S 0
705. Ki Dy 11/21/2012     12:49 PM S 0

Comment: Sorry about all the confusion, I had difficulty entering some more samples for you.  It is all in there, I just do not know how to attach a screen image.  Anyway, I think that you understand my issue and I am certain that the answer is here somewhere!

Comment: OK, I accept your modifications for the spreadsheet which is in fact how I had set it up.  I want it to find the last Successful call.  Now I have modified the above data, but the letters do correspond to consistent names, ie. 698 and 700 are the same person.  In 698, my first attempt was unsuccessful, in 700 however, I made successful contact with the client and wish to start the count over.  I also need to note here that S ~ represents a successful contact, but not with my intended recipient, so it too will not qualify as a Successful call.